# What does "bxa1=Q" mean?

Tags: notation

I have a PGN file with the following move in it:

> 11. fxe5 bxa1=Q

I understand the equals sign represents a draw offer, but what does "=Q" mean?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I would read it as "Pawn takes something on `a1` and promotes to a Queen".

Strictly according to the [Laws of Chess](http://www.fide.com/fide/handbook.html?id=171&view=article) the `=` sign should not be there (see article C.11).

> C.11
>   In the case of the promotion of a pawn, the actual pawn move is indicated, followed immediately by the abbreviation of the new piece. Examples: d8Q, exf8N, b1B, g1R.

However this is a PGN file, which has its own rules for game notation and it uses the `=` sign for pawn promotion (see paragraph 3 of article 8.2.3.3 in the [PGN standard specification](http://www6.chessclub.com/help/PGN-spec) also available [here](http://www.saremba.de/chessgml/standards/pgn/pgn-complete.htm), which should probably be the official reference).

> [...]. Pawn promotions are denoted by the equal sign "=" immediately following the destination square with a promoted piece letter (indicating one of knight, bishop, rook, or queen) immediately following the equal sign. As above, the piece letter is in uppercase.

Draw data is handled in so-called  *EPD records* for describing chess positions, using verbose opcodes like `draw_offer`.  Although it isn't included in PGN proper, specifics are included in articles 16.2.5.8 - 16.2.5.11 of the standard.

Answer (score 0):

it meant a pawn on b captured something on a1
and promoted to a queen

this is normal notation

why they want =  to be on the end of a score sheet for a tie is ridiculous

1/2 - 1/2  always worked well to denote a tie

and =x has been used for promoting to piece x 
for the 67 years i have played chess

Comment: This post adds nothing useful to an already given answer. I suggest that you delete it.

Comment: It is a valid answer.  Should not be deleted.